# Oauth-авторизация. Как связаны окна браузера

Tags: php, html, oauth

Есть сайт с авторизацией через VK.

Кнопка войти выполненна через ссылку и имеет вид `<a href='link'  target='_blank'>Войти</a>`

Нажимаем кнопку войти - открывается новая вкладка. Переходит на контакт, потом на файл `login.php` если пользователь дает разрешение. Данные вытаскиваются и пишутся в сессию. Здесь все работает и в целом все ясно.

Дальше... окно должно закрыться, браузер вернуться на старую вкладку и страница основного сайта должна перезагрузиться или обновить часть себя через AJAX.

**Как связаны новая вкладка и основная? Каким образом передать ответ, что авторизация прошла обратно на сайт?**

Comment: куда обратно? какие данные? непонятно

Comment: Алексей, в первую страницу как передать то, что авторизация прошла. Это происходит всегда мгновенно. То есть они как-то связаны со стороны браузера. Я не понимаю как.

Comment: Капаю сейчас в сторону всплывающих окнон. Похоже там собака зарыта.

Comment: так там же передается `redirect_url` и когда авторизация происходит то автоматом тебя должно перекинуть на страницу, указанную в redirect_url и содержать GET параметр `code`, на основе которого получаешь токен и работаешь с ним

Comment: Алексей, не в том направлении мыслите. Да есть редирект и он стоит на login.php и можно с него перейти на основную страницу сайта, в этом случае все происходит в одном окне. А должно быть в двух окнах.

Comment: что значит "должно быть в двух окнах"?

Comment: Давайте проще на примере https://www.hypercomments.com/ru/demo?type=media Когда выбираете авторизацию - открывается второе окно. В котором и происходит присвоение переменных и их запись в сессию. После этого второе окно закрывается и первое сразу обновляется. Мгновенно. Как они связаны в обратном направоении? Как второе оно передает данные первому?

Comment: да никак они не связаны... данные после редиректа тебе попадают в файл логин...а раз так, значит ты уже знаешь, что что-то произошло..... просто берешь и обновляешь основную страницу любым удобным способом......

Comment: Нет. В принципе ответ накопал сам. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно открывать не вторую вкладку а pop-окно в скрипте через `window.open`. И обращаться к первой странице через `window.opener`